# Error in using Pandas groupby.apply to drop duplication

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, valueerror

I have a Pandas data frame which has some duplicate values, not rows. I want to use `groupby.apply` to remove the duplication. An example is as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1], ['a', 1, 2], ['b', 1, 1]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
   A  B  C
0  a  1  1
1  a  1  2
2  b  1  1

# My function
def get_uniq_t(df):
    if df.shape[0] > 1:
        df['D'] = df.C * 10 + df.B
        df = df[df.D == df.D.max()].drop(columns='D')
    return df

df = df.groupby('A').apply(get_uniq_t)
```

Then I get the following value error message. The issue seems to do with creating the new column D. If I create the column D outside the function, the code seems running fine. Can someone help explain what caused the value error message?

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it attempts to modify
the original group.

Other problem is that this function should return a **single row**
not a DataFrame.

Change your function to:

```
def get_uniq_t(df):
    iMax = (df.C * 10 + df.B).idxmax()
    return df.loc[iMax]
```

Then its application returns:

```
   A  B  C
A         
a  a  1  2
b  b  1  1
```

## Edit following the comment

In my opinion, it is not allowed to modify the **original** group,
as it would indirectly modify the original DataFrame.

At least it displays a warning about this and is considered a bad practice.
Search the Web for *SettingWithCopyWarning* for more extensive description.

My code (*get_uniq_t* function) does **not** modify the original group.
It only returns **one** row from the current group.

The returned row is selected based on which row returns the greatest value
of `df.C * 10 + df.B`. So when you apply this function, the result is a new
DataFrame, with consecutive rows equal to results of this function
for consecutive groups.

You can perform an operation equivalent to modification, when you
**create** some new content, e.g. as the result of *groupby* instruction
and then save it under the same variable which so far held the source
DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate more? I intended to modify the original group. Do you mean this is not allowed? Your answer also modifies the original group, right? Regarding your 2nd point, do you mean  df[[False, True]] returns a single row, not a DataFrame?